# MS Access VBA XML POST Using HTTP Using msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0

Tags: xml, vba, http, ms-access, post

I am fairly good Access and with VBA but have limited exposure to XML and http requests.
I am trying to return some XML structured data, by doing an  HTTTP POST using the below code.
(My apologies if I am not phrasing that correctly)

This is the  error I am getting:

```
{"message":"Request could not be processed","details":null,"responseCode":500,"code":null,"target":null}
```

Initially I had a problem with the API secret failing and now I am past that error and know that is correct.

1. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?
2. Could it be  the way I have constructed the XML
3. Should the request XML also include header information and the other header information is for  the response?
4. Do I need this `objXML.async = False` I just copied that from someone elses code

```
    Sub MFGetRate()
    'Add a reference to Microsoft XML v6.0 via Tools > References
    
    
    Dim sGetResult              As String
    Dim httpObject              As Object
    Dim objXML                  As Object
    Dim sXML                    As String
    Dim apiURL                  As String
    
    Set objXML = CreateObject("msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    Set httpObject = CreateObject("msxml2.serverxmlhttp.6.0")
    
    
    objXML.async = False
    
    
        sXML = "<rate>"
        sXML = sXML & "<account>"
        sXML = sXML & "<code>XXXX</code>"
        sXML = sXML & "</account>"
        sXML = sXML & "<serviceLevel>"
        sXML = sXML & "<code>M2H</code>"
        sXML = sXML & "</serviceLevel>"
        sXML = sXML & "<origin>"
        sXML = sXML & "<freightRequiredDateTime>2021-11-04T17:33:10</freightRequiredDateTime>"
        sXML = sXML & "<freightRequiredDateTimeZone>New Zealand Standard Time</freightRequiredDateTimeZone>"
        sXML = sXML & "<address>"
        sXML = sXML & "<suburb>Rosedale</suburb>"
        sXML = sXML & "<postCode>0000</postCode>"
        sXML = sXML & "<town/>"
        sXML = sXML & "<city>Auckland</city>"
        sXML = sXML & "<stateCode/>"
        sXML = sXML & "<countryCode>NZ</countryCode>"
        sXML = sXML & "</address>"
        sXML = sXML & "</origin>"
        sXML = sXML & "<destination>"
        sXML = sXML & "<address>"
        sXML = sXML & "<suburb>XXXXXX</suburb>"
        sXML = sXML & "<postCode>0000</postCode>"
        sXML = sXML & "<town/>"
        sXML = sXML & "<city>XXXXXX</city>"
        sXML = sXML & "<stateCode/>"
        sXML = sXML & "<countryCode>NZ</countryCode>"
        sXML = sXML & "</address>"
        sXML = sXML & "</destination>"
        sXML = sXML & "<freightDetails>"
        sXML = sXML & "<units>1</units>"
        sXML = sXML & "<packTypeCode>CTN</packTypeCode>"
        sXML = sXML & "<height/>"
        sXML = sXML & "<length/>"
        sXML = sXML & "<width/>"
        sXML = sXML & "<weight>30</weight>"
        sXML = sXML & "<volume>.1</volume>"
        sXML = sXML & "</freightDetails>"
        sXML = sXML & "</rate>"
    
    
    objXML.Load (sXML)
    
    
    apiURL = "https://api.mainfreight.com/transport/1.0/Customer/Rate?region=NZ"
    
     sRequest = apiURL
     httpObject.Open "POST", sRequest, False
     httpObject.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
     httpObject.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Secret XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     httpObject.Send objXML.XML
     
     
     sGetResult = httpObject.responseText
    
    Debug.Print sGetResult
    
    
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Based on the [API documentation](https://developer.mainfreight.com/global/en/global-home/transport-api/rate.aspx) (It will be great if you can provide relevant documentation in your question so we don't have to google for it...), it seems that you are missing `<freightDetail>` tag within `<freightDetails>` tag. Try inserting `sXML = sXML & "<freightDetail>"` before `sXML = sXML & "<units>1</units>"` and `sXML = sXML & "</freightDetail>"` before `sXML = sXML & "</freightDetails>"`

Comment: And you might be able to just pass `sXML` directly, i.e. `httpObject.Send sXML`

Comment: It helps to use an API testing tool such as {Postman](https://www.postman.com/)), because it's easy to modify request parameters there. Once you have found something that is proven to work with your API, you'll know exactly what to re-implement with XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: You've not added the required "Accept" header to the POST request.   https://developer.mainfreight.com/global/en/global-home/transport-api/rate.aspx#:~:text=Result%20content%20type.%20Supported%20types%20are%20%22application/json%22%20or%20%22application/xml%22

Comment: The "Accept" header is not required so i believe he can omit it. (Though a good idea to specify which format he wants as the response) @TimWilliams

Comment: @raymondwu - the API docs say the Accept header is required

Comment: That's not what I read from the doc though, its say "No" under the "Required" column. Nonetheless it's good measure that OP include it. @TimWilliams

Comment: @RaymondWu - you’re right. on mobile I only saw the “you must add” and didn’t scroll over to the right…

Comment: Thanks @RaymondWu, noted regarding documentation. Although the notes on the Mainfreight site do suggest that I need <freightDetail> tags, the helpdesk told me it was causing an error and to remove. I'll try to pass the xml text directly to the .send and add the optional header.

Comment: @RaymondWu, you were right it was passing a string to httpObject.Send rather than the xml object that did the trick. I am now trying to work out how to accept your answer, mark as solved.  `httpObject.Send sXML`

Comment: @DeanGraham Click the tick beside the answer to accept it. (You can only accept 1 answer if there are multiple answers submitted)

Answer (score 0):

Send the request body as a string:

`httpObject.Send sXML`